# How to add an Image and a Textblock into a WPF ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I have a ContentControl in WPF,which has an image in it

```
ContentControl myContentControl = new ContentControl();
myContentControl.Content = image;
```

How do I to add a textblock next to the image inside the ContentControl?
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of adding the image directly, first add a stack panel with horizontal orientation, then add the image and textblock to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing looks like you are not familiar with `MVVM`:
Please check [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

**Easy Solution**

But if you want the ugly solution and create `UIElement`s in your code behind - go like this:

```
    public static ContentControl CreateControl(string title, Uri path)
    {
        //Create your image
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(path);
        Image image = new Image()
        {
            Source = bitmapImage
        };

        //Create your Text
        TextBlock textB = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = title
        };

        //Put them together
        StackPanel content = new StackPanel();
        content.Children.Add(image);
        content.Children.Add(textB);

        //Add this to the content control
        return new ContentControl()
        {
            Content = content
        };

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the MVVM link.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the property `ContentTemplate` of the contentControl, as to `ContentTemplate`, here is some explanation:

> Gets or sets the data template used to display the content of the ContentControl.

Also you need create a class to represent your data, like this:

```
public class ImageInfo
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

It is better to create `ContentControl` in XAML, like this:

```
    <ContentControl x:Name="cc">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
```

Then, assign the data to the ContentControl:

```
cc.Content = new ImageInfo() { Caption = "Hello", Image = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("/Assets/User.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) };
```

Comment: Thank you.  I need to add these contentcontrol(s) dynamically, e.g. to be able to add and remove the contentcontrol by user clicking buttons.  I have almost all of it done from the background.  Although binding data to xmal sounds a better way doing so, but how?